# Perceptron mistake bound when dataset is not linearly separable

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I'm struggling to understand the intuition behind a mistake bound for online `Perceptron`, which I found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.8200&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

In section 3.1, the authors introduce a mistake bound for Perceptron, assuming that the dataset is linearly separable.

In section 3.2, the authors derive a mistake bound for Perceptron, this time assuming that the dataset is *inseparable*. Leaving the algebra aside for a moment, their proof is a reduction of the inseparable case to the separable case in a higher dimention. That is, they construct new `x` vectors (the inputs), and a new weight vector `w`, both in a higher dimension, and that new `w` could linearly separate the new `x` vectors. They then prove that this new dataset is linearly separable, so they could essentially use the mistake bound found in Section 3.1.

My question is: isn't there a problem using the mistake bound found in section 3.1? That is, in section 3.2 they projected their dataset to a higher dimension; doesn't that imply that the "regular" perceptron cannot be used any longer? Aren't they supposed to be using some kind of kernel-perceptron, thus making the original perceptron bound irrelevant?

Thanks.

Comment: I'll ask my professor Freund this weekend :)

Comment: @eggie5 - if you were serious then - _wow_, thanks!! :) :) :)